# Spring JPA @Query throws Optional parameter exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@Query("from Category c inner join fetch c.products where c.id=:id")
List<Product> findProductByCategoryId(@Param("category_id") int id);
```

throws Exception with this message

> ... but parameter 'Optional[category_id]' not found in annotated query 'from Category c inner join fetch c.products where c.id=:id'!

I don't understand this error. Any explanation?

Answer (score 1):

The bind variable you are using is id but it should be "category_id"

```
c.id=:category_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to `@Query("from Category c inner join fetch c.products where c.id=:category_id")`.
Spring cannot find param with name `category_id` in query you provided.